# DSN name does not appear in Excel

Tags: oracle, 64-bit, odbc, dsn

My notebook has Windows 8 64 bit, Microsoft office 2010 32 bit and Oracle DB 11gR2 64 bit installed. I have created DSN to access oracle databases via ODBC sources 64 bit. I want to obtain data from oracle database to Microsoft Excel or Access via ODBC (in excel -> Data - From other sources - from Microsoft query). But DSN name that I created earlier do not appear. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

If the Application that wants to Access an ODBC-Datasource is 32bit, you need to use the 32bit version of the ODBC-Driver.

In your case you use a 32bit Version of Microsoft Office to Access the Datasource, so you need to use the 32bit Version of the ODBC-Driver. Configure your DSN using

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe
```

and they will probably show up in the 32bit Version of Office.